# How to switch back to default theme, if user specified theme property file is not present in application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have 3 theme property files:-
1) theme-fr_CA
2) theme-fr_US
3) theme-en_US

In my spring application based on user locale theme is applied. but, my problem is if there is some unknown locale like 'ch_RS' then I want be fall back to theme belonging to en_US locale that is theme-en_US file.

Please find the below code:-

```
    <bean id="themeSource"
      class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
</bean>

<bean id="themeResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <property name="defaultThemeName" value="en_US" />
</bean>
```

How can I achieve this? Help very much appreciated.

Comment: I feel I am correct there is no need of any change as I am specifically talking about switching back to default "theme" and not "locale".                              I know how to redirect user to default "locale" I do not have any issue with that....I can do it using the property  <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>  , it's working fine. My question is switching back to default theme & it's still open.

Comment: I stand corrected and will withdraw my comment immediately.

Comment: The solution to the problem is to add a customThemeResolver and not to go with default springFrmeework CookieThemeResolver..it solved my problem....thnx.